# Returning a struct created by serde_json in a function

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I'm stuck on what seems like a simple issue. I get *why* I am seeing the error but can't seem to resolve it. Obviously I am missing something fundamental.

```
fn terraform_deploy_info<'a>(app: &'a MyApp) -> std::result::Result<&MyAppDeployInfo, Error> {
    let terraform = process::Command::new("terraform")
          // We are querying output values.
          .arg("output")
          // We want it in json format for easy processing.
          .arg("-json")
          .output()
          .expect("failed to execute terraform");

    let output = String::from_utf8_lossy(&terraform.stdout);
    let data: TerraformOutputs = serde_json::from_str(&output).unwrap();

    let m = data.deploy_info.value.iter().filter(|&x| x.app == "myapp").collect::<Vec<_>>();

    if m.len() > 1 {
        return Err(Error::MultipleDeployInfo);
    }

    match m.get(0) {
        Some(&x) => Ok(x),
        None => Err(Error::NoDeployInfo),
    }
}
```

The error I get is:

```
borrowed value must be valid for the lifetime 'a as defined on the body at
```

Which makes sense to me, as I am creating the struct in the function and returning a borrowed reference, which of course goes away when the function is finished.

*But*, when I change the return type be `std::result::Result<MyAppDeployInfo, Error>` (that is, not returning a reference) I can't seem to get `Ok(x)` to work...I get an error:

```
expected struct `MyAppDeployInfo`, found reference
```

Again, this makes sense as `serde_json` creates a structure and then I iterate through references, so when I index into the collection I am looking at a reference.

So I tried all sorts of things to get the struct value like dereferencing, `Box::new`, `clone()`, `to_owned()`, etc and still can't get it to work.

I've searched all the issues here, read the book, etc and it is still not clear to me how I can resolve this...any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without knowing more about your project (please produce an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) next time), I'd say that you can change the `.iter()` call into `.into_iter()`. Instead of collecting into a `Vec` and then using `get`, I'd simply work with the iterator directly:

```
let m = data.deploy_info.value.into_iter().filter(|&x| x.app == "myapp").fuse();

match (m.next(), m.next()) {
    (None, None) => Err(Error::NoDeployInfo),
    (Some(x), None) => Ok(x),
    (Some(_), Some(_)) => Err(Error::MultipleDeployInfo),
    (None, Some(_)) => panic!("Iterator::fuse broken"),
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! `into_iter()` and not using `collect()` was what I was missing. It now works.

Answer (score 2):

Observe the types of your snippet.

```
let m = data.deploy_info.value // value is a Vec<MyAppDeployInfo>
    .iter() // returns a Iterator<Item=&MyAppDeployInfo>
    .filter(|&x| x.app == "myapp")
    .collect::<Vec<_>>(); // collects into a Vec<&MyAppDeployInfo>

if m.len() > 1 {
    return Err(Error::MultipleDeployInfo);
}

match m.get(0) { // get() returns a reference to an element
                 // i.e. a &&MyAppDeployInfo
        Some(&x) // pattern match says x : &MyAppDeployInfo
            => Ok(x), // which matches the return type
                      // but you get a borrowing error.
        None => Err(Error::NoDeployInfo),
    }
}
```

Now if you change the return type to `Result<MyAppDeployInfo, Error>` as you should, you get the mismatched type issue, because `x` is a reference. If you dereference `x`, you get the error "cannot move out of borrowed content", because `MyAppDeployInfo` is not `Copy`, and you're trying to move. If you write `x.clone()`, it should work, unless you changed something else?

Alternatively, you can, from the beginning, work with moving content around. If you write `data.deploy_info.value.into_iter().filter(|x| x.app == "myapp")`, you move out of the initial structure instead of copying it. Then the resulting `Vec` will have `MyAppDeployInfo` as its item type. Then you could make it `mut` and use `pop()` instead of `get(0)` to get the only element in a way that you can move out of.

Or you can do what @ker recommended and not use `collect()` in the first place. I'd still switch to `into_iter()` though, making this the final code:

```
fn terraform_deploy_info(app: &MyApp) // no explicit lifetime needed
        -> std::result::Result<MyAppDeployInfo, Error> {
    let data = // ...

    let mut m = data.deploy_info.value.into_iter()
        .filter(|x| x.app == "myapp").fuse();

    match (m.next(), m.next()) {
        (None, None) => Err(Error::NoDeployInfo),
        (Some(x), None) => Ok(x),
        (Some(_), Some(_)) => Err(Error::MultipleDeployInfo),
        (None, Some(_)) => panic!("Iterator::fuse broken"),
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the detailed explanation! I totally understand it now.